# LoadError: cannot load such file -- rvm/capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

I want deploy sinatra project.

Run command `cap production deploy`.

errors:

```
cap aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- rvm/capistrano
config/deploy.rb:1:in `require'
config/deploy.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/cap:23:in `load'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/cap:23:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'

#gemfile
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem "rake"
gem "sinatra"
gem "sinatra-activerecord"
gem "sinatra-flash"
gem "pg"
gem "bcrypt"
gem "pry"
gem "pony"
gem "capistrano", '~> 3.1.0'
gem "capistrano-bundler", '~> 1.1.2'
gem "capistrano-rvm", github: "capistrano/rvm"
```

Setting capistrano Capgile file

## Capfile

```
# Load DSL and set up stages
require 'capistrano/setup'

# Include default deployment tasks
require 'capistrano/deploy'

# If you are using rvm add these lines:
require 'capistrano/rvm'
set :rvm_type, :user
set :rvm_ruby_version, '2.3.1-p112'
#Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

In deploy file i added folowing settng for rvm

```
#config/deploy.rb
#RVM and bundler settings
set :bundle_cmd, "/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1-p112@global/bin/bundle"
set :bundle_dir, "/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1-p112/gems"
set :rvm_ruby_string, :local
set :rack_env, :production
```

I dont undestand why this error, maybe becose First time on local I used rbenv for installing ruby and bundle install gems. But after installed rvm, in directory project select right version ruby with command `rvm use 2.3.1.`

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]
```

How solve this issue? Thank you for advance.

Comment: can you use rvm-capistrano gem? @stefan

Comment: `  gem 'capistrano-rails'
  gem 'capistrano-rvm'` I have these in my gem file

Comment: can you add gem 'capistrano-rails' as well you have added gem "capistrano"

Comment: Oh yes sorry for that missed that

Comment: The answer for this is already in SO... couldn't find it though... you need to add `require: false` to `gem "capistrano-rvm", github: "capistrano/rvm"` in your Gemfile

Comment: i added, same error cap aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- rvm/capistrano